# Converting uint16_t to float in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

**Problem Statement:**

I am currently processing image data in CUDA through a kernel. What I'll do in that kernel when it's complete is irrelevant for this conversation. Before I get to the fun stuff of developing the inner workings of the kernel, I'm writing a passthrough function that reads data from one buffer, converts it to float, and then pushes that data into another buffer.

You can see from the function signature that I'm passing in a pointer to uint64_t data and passing out a pointer to float. Inside the kernel, I bit shift the uint64_t data into four chunks of uint16_t data. From here, in order to get to float, I run each uint16_t through two conversion functions: `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));`

- Yes, CUDA recognizes the uint16_t and uint64_t data types.
- i can technically perform the function: `uint16_t val = 4; float fVal = val;` in CUDA
- but it yields a very different float value than `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));` does.
- i am including `stdint` because both host and device have no issue with the uint64_t or uint16_t variables.

---

**Question:**

Does anyone know if there's an easier way to convert from `uint16_t` to `float` in CUDA, while maintaining the same numeric results that `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));` yields?

---

**CODE**

```
__global__ void _64bitPassThrough(const uint64_t *in, float *out, const int w, const int h, const int n)
{
    int position = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int maxval = w * h;

    if (position < maxval)
    {
        uint16_t a = (in[position] >> 48);
        uint16_t b = (in[position] >> 32) & 0xffff;
        uint16_t g = (in[position] >> 16) & 0xffff;
        uint16_t r = in[position] & 0xffff;
        int new_position = n * position;

        out[new_position + 0] = __half2float(__ushort_as_half(r));
        out[new_position + 1] = __half2float(__ushort_as_half(g));
        out[new_position + 2] = __half2float(__ushort_as_half(b));
        out[new_position + 3] = __half2float(__ushort_as_half(a));
    }
}
```

---

**Operating Parameters:**

- *OS*: Windows 10
- *GPU*: GeForce GTX 960M
- *Compute Capability*: compute_50,sm_50
- *CUDA Ver*: 9.0
- *IDE & Compiler*: Visual Studio 2015 Community & MSVC

---

**Sidebar:**

I'm open to answering questions you may have about my approach. I will explain as best I can and take all relevant and useful advice as befits the project.

Comment: regarding this: "I cannot do the same on the device, ie. in CUDA code."  Not sure what you mean by that.  It works fine for me.

Comment: @Robert, do you get the same numeric value as well?

Comment: Yes, I get the results I expect.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/S3hy2tNp) is a fully worked test case.

Comment: Question has been edited to make clearer what I'm looking for and the results i need to achieve.

Comment: Do you get the same numeric return as using `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));`?

Comment: `__ushort_as_half` converts a ushort bit pattern into a bitwise-identical half (16 bit floating point) quantity.  I don't see how this could possibly be sensible for converting a 16 bit integer into a 32-bit floating point quantity.  And it certainly also does not give you the same result as the host operation  of `float fa = a;`

Comment: `__ushort_as_half` would be used if you actually had four 16-bit floating point quantities packed into a 64-bit integer, that you wanted to expand into 4 independent float quantities.  But if you actually have four 16-bit integer quantities, it's not the right function to use.

Comment: I'm dealing with image data coming from a video input buffer.  `__ushort_as_half()` is an excellent function because it's the only way i can get the data to `__half` type. Ideally, I'd stay in `__half` type but everything I'm reading says that numeric operations on __half aren't ready yet, at least not in a robust manner beyond simple arithmetic. I'd be happy to be wrong here.

Comment: If you want to load 4 short values from a single 64 bit source, then the `ushort4` vector type does exactly what you want without any bit fiddling. After that, nothing you have described makes much sense, I am afraid.

Comment: You're still not grasping the point.  The concern here is not around what format you want to get to, but what format you are starting with.  If you are starting with 4 packed 16-bit integer quantities, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @talonmies, if you post that as an answer, and it works, I'll happily give you credit.

Comment: @Robert, if you have an actual answer, and it works for my project, I'll up vote it. Your condemnation of my approach is far more cryptic than anything I've written yet. Show me how to do it better.

Comment: Using your `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x))` construct, I can easily get output quantities that are between 0 and 1, for example 0.000061.  Is this what you expect?  It's not what I would expect for conversion of an integer (`uint16_t`) to a floating point quantity, which seems to be the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I've noticed though, that while on host code in c, I can say uint16_t
>   val = 4; float fVal = val;, I cannot do the same on the device, ie. in
>   CUDA code.

You totally can. You have not explained what made you think that you can't, but I guess you just need to tell to the compiler the definition of `uint16_t`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

<sub>Sidenote: Next time you will be asking for help, make sure to ask about the problem itself and to provide all the pieces if information (e.g. compiler's error messages). Do not ask (only) about your interpretation of the problem or the attempted solution. See:  [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).</sub>

Comment: There's no compiler error message. The error is that the numeric result is different between the two approaches, whereas in c, it wouldn't be.

Comment: You've simply made a mistake.  Since you haven't shown the code that demonstrates the error you've made, nobody can help you.  Posting working code doesn't help others help you understand what you did wrong in the code that is not working that you haven't shown.

Comment: Then the code is not equivalent. You need to post: CPU-only code, CUDA host and device code, input data, expected outputs and observed outputs.

Comment: Please check your results against the return of `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));` since that was mentioned as working in the question, and also what I'm trying to replace her keep the same numeric return.

Comment: My question is does anyone know of an easier way to perform: `__half2float(__ushort_as_half(x));` and still get the same numeric return. My question explains that i have working code and asks only if someone knows how to perform the same result in fewer steps.

Comment: You also claimed that you could do it in fewer steps in host code but not in device code (now edited into a sentence that makes no sense.) That claim is false.  It's entirely unclear why you would be using `__ushort_as_half` if you actually have 16 bit integers that you want to covert to 32-bit floating point.

Comment: I've read the question multiple times. It makes sense. I'm asking for help. I've clarified my question to be more specific in order to aid people.

Comment: This sentence makes no sense to me: " I've noticed though, that while on host code in c, I can say , I cannot do the same on the device, ie. in CUDA code and get the same numeric value."  The original version of that sentence claimed something I disagreed with, and the answerer here apparently interpreted it the same way and disagreed with it also.  You've failed to answer my question about what format the source is in.  Without that information, I can't provide anything useful.

Comment: Robert, you never asked the format of the source. I read your comments multiple times. It's late, so maybe i missed it. Fundamentally, people are disagreeing with a statement, that i clarified, which contains a typo, and only one person has actually sought to address the actual question, which is under the *Question* heading. I think at this point, only @talonmies has addressed the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easier way. You've got a 16-bit integer, and you want to interpret those bits as a half and then expand the half to a float, which is exactly the code you've written. I don't know how there could be any easier way except a `ushort_to_float_via_half` helper function.